# Django views: postgres materialized view accessible via get but not via filter (both queryset)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-views, geodjango, materialized-views

I try to filter materialized postgres views in Django views.py. The database and the views were created with postgres. I can filter views which represent one to many relationships and I can access views with get (queryset) which represent many to many relationships. But I cannot filter those views which represent many to many relationships. Models were created with inspectdb. It's a postgis legacy database.

How do I have to filter these views?

models.py

```
    fid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_dokument = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dokument = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    datei = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    beschreibung = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    datum = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    person = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    dokumenttyp = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    id_objekt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    objekt = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'objekt_dokumente_rel'
```

views.py

```
dokumente = ObjektDokumenteRel.objects.using('db').filter(id_objekt=fid)
```

If replacing filter with get I receive one object (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Adding __exact to id_objekt `dokumente = ObjektDokumenteRel.objects.using('db').filter(id_objekt__exact=fid)` resolves the problem. Has anyone an idea why?